# Implement notification system using node.js,express,socket

Tags: node.js, express, notifications, push-notification, socket.io

I am trying to add a notification system. If a user logs in and performs an action a notification should be sent to another user if he is logged in. I have made my application in node.js using express. I know that I have to use socket but how the event needs to be handled? If someone could let me know any reference or sample which I can follow for this task?

Comment: It's not clear what part is missing. In my chat the event is handled by a socket.io client and I use the [Notification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/notification) API to display it to the user ([relevant code](https://github.com/Canop/miaou/blob/master/src%2Fmain-js%2Fmiaou.horn.js#L65))

Comment: @NKMY did you try anything yet? Or you want to know how socket works?

Comment: You can read this as a reference http://www.gianlucaguarini.com/blog/nodejs-and-a-simple-push-notification-server/

In short, you need to maintain the global list of users online and their respective socket connection. So, whenever a user makes any action you can use the global list to select your targeted user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just did something similar and handled it like this:

*io.js* - central node.js file where I handle new connnections and store io

```
var io = require('socket.io')();

io.on('connection', function(socket){
 console.log("Socket established with id: " + socket.id);

 socket.on('disconnect', function () {
  console.log("Socket disconnected: " + socket.id);
 });

});

module.exports = io;
```

*someroute.js* - somewhere in the node.js server application I want to emit messages

```
var appRoot = require('app-root-path');
var io = require(appRoot + '/server/io');

/*your code, somwhere you will call the
 * function below whenever you want to emit
 * the 'user_did_action' event:
*/
if(user.didNewStuff()){
 emitUserAction(user);
}

var emitUserAction = function(user){
  io.sockets.emit('user_did_action', user);
};
```

*client_javascript.js* - some client js (in my case angular, but it doesent matter), import the socket.io lib, then access somewhere in the client like this:

```
/*connect to the server*/
var socket = io.connect();

/*do something wen the event 'user_did_action'
 * is received, just invoke the callback
 *
 *in the function param data, you will have the same
 *data you emitted earlier in the server, 
 *in this example the user object!*/
socket.on('user_did_action', myFunctionToHandleTheEvent(data));
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Do u know any reference or example of utility class for this socket notifications is provided.

Comment: [Here](https://codeforgeek.com/2015/09/real-time-notification-system-using-socket-io/) you can find a quite elaborate tutorial/example of a notification application using node.js and socket.io

Comment: Thanks @risuch for the link.